# Multiplicative Group of Complex Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

It is my understanding that a group must satisfy the requirements of

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Invertibility
4. Identity.

so....

1. If you multiply two complex numbers, you get a complex number back.
2. The order in which you do so does not matter.
3. $z^{-1} = z^*/(zz^*)$
4. But what is the identity element in the multiplicative group of complex numbers? Doesn't this mean that some complex number should exist, whereby, multiplication by it returns the same number? Of course the number $1$ does this, but $1$ is a real number. Or do we just consider $1 + 0i$ to be the identity element?

Comment: $1+0i=1$ is the identity element.

Comment: Every real number is a complex number.

Comment: ... and if you didn't include real numbers in $\mathbb{C}$ then $i^2=-1$ would break the closure rule.

Comment: The way you phrase your thinking through the second rule makes it seem like you're considering the multiplication of two complex numbers, not three. As it happens complex numbers are commutative too, we say they're an Abelian group.

Comment: Just to reinforce what J.G. says.  Check the definitions of associativity and commutativity.  Associativity is required but commutativity is optional.  You seem to have considered commutativity.  Associativity requires $x(yz) = (xy)z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity of $(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\times)$ is $1$. Yes, $1$ is a real number, but all real numbers are complex numbers too.

Comment: Interesting! Very cool! Thank you :)

Comment: What kind of construction has $1 \in \mathbb{C}$? I've only seen constructions of the complex numbers as $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Then $1=(1,0)$.